# Why is function producing wrong solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
   <script>
    function range (start , end ) {
      var list =[]
      for (var count = start ; count <= end ; count++)
        list.push(count);
      return list
    }

    function sum ( nums ) {
      var total = 0;
      for ( var count = 0 ; count <= nums.length ; count++ )
        total = total + nums[count];
      return total;
    }

    console.log(range(1 , 10))
    console.log(sum(range(1 ,10)))
    </script>
```

When I run this, the output from my `sum` function will be `NaN`. I know the solution is to remove the `=` from the `sum` function however I do not understand how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating beyond the bounds of the `nums` array.
As such, in the last iteration of the loop you effectively execute `total = total + undefined`, the result of which is `NaN`.
Try for example in a JavaScript console, `n + undefined` results in `NaN`, where `n` is any number.

Change the loop condition to `count < nums.length` instead of `<=`:

```
  for ( var count = 0 ; count < nums.length ; count++ )
    total = total + nums[count];
```

Answer (score 1):

when you <= that means you are including the end number. all arrays are `0` indexed, meaning the first item is at index 0

for an array of 10 items, this means the the last index is 9

also for incrementing an existing number you can use `+=`

```js
function range (start , end ) {
  var list =[]

  //here you want INCLUSIVE because you are starting 
  //at VALUE 1 and ending at VALUE 10
  for (var count = start ; count <= end ; count++)
    list.push(count);
  return list
}

function sum ( nums ) {
  var total = 0;

  //here you want EXCLUSIVE because you are starting
  //at INDEX 0 and ending at INDEX 9
  for ( var count = 0 ; count < nums.length ; count++ )
    total += nums[count];
  return total;
}

console.log(sum(range(1,10)))
```